# While loops and input functions are not working in python

Tags: python, input, while-loop

I've been trying to work on practice modules in the python crash course book. I'm working on while loops and input functions. I tried running the below code in the terminal but only the second line of code prints.

`What rental car would you like?`

The full code is below:

```
while True:
    car = input("What rental car would you like?")
    print(f'Let me see if I can find you a {car.title()}.')
    car += input('Subaru')
    break
while True:
    table = input("How many people are in your party?")
    table = int(table)
    if table > 8:
        print('My apologies, you will have to wait for a table.')
    else:
        print('Your table is ready!')
        break
```

I tried breaking the loops apart to get the rest to print in the terminal but I'm not sure where I'm messing up. I don't get any errors, it just only prints one line of code out of the entire thing.

Comment: It is waiting for your input.

Comment: If you would like to, you can add in your post an expected outcome and the outcome that you get

Comment: The statement `answer = input("Question: ")` tells the computer to print the `Question:` and then wait for input a line of from the console.
So when you see `What rental car would you like?` on the screen you should type in the answer to the question and the answer will be stored in the `car` variable.

Comment: @vorrade Thank you so much! I'm a noob to programming and didn't think to do that. It's working smoothly now, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is waiting for your input. After you write something and hit enter it will proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I did not quite understand the first while loop, but for the second one the problem is with the indentation of the break statement

Comment: I disagree; I think that the `break` only applies when the table is ready.